# Python Code Sharing Forum

Tags: python, code-example

I have recently switch from SmallBasic to Python for my introduction to programming course.  I have managed to translate everything from one language to the other... with a single difficulty.

Over the decade of teaching the course I amassed dozens of examples. Examples twenty five lines or less showing the basics. Examples with hundreds of lines showing what is possible. Programs to that stick to the basics and will run on any system. Programs that do amazing things by importing libraries.  Programs that follow the one command per line rule. Programs that squish as much onto a line as possible.

And now I have none of it for Python. I have found a few examples here and there, but it requires a lot of searching.

What I'm looking for is a place where people share their Python accomplishments. Little test apps that show off an idea.  Something big they managed cram into a few lines.  Something expansive that takes up multiple files.

Does this Python corner of the internet exist?

Comment: It sounds like what you have is lovely, very idiosyncratic, and quite beneficial to the students.  I don't believe you will find such a collection, but I would love to be proven wrong.  Little, deeply thoughtful *discoveries* are not the main and the plain, and the larger resources stick to that.

Comment: Yea... I've been scouring the internet looking for something like a forum where people share their achievements. Something like Creative Computing in the late 70's.  Nothing so far.

Comment: I tend to post my code snippets in [this discord server](https://discord.gg/programming). Usually short snippets, sometimes larger stuff.